# CSS centering text with long words

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, center

Is there a straightforward way to horizontally center text that works even when really long words need to stretch out into the surrounding padding?

For example, the following:

**HTML**

```
<section>
   <p>
      Some animals in the wild, like
      hummingbirds, have long names.
   </p>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section p {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gold;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Results in "hummingbirds" being off-centered:

[image: Off-centered "hummingbirds"]

If the word "hummingbirds" was properly centered, it would fit nicely within the gold box.

Fiddle with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/m6h37q2z/

**ADDED NOTE #1:**
This question is NOT about how to remove the padding or reduce the font size or make the box bigger... those are all very easy tweaks (and would break the design).  This question is about how to center the word "hummingbirds".

**ADDED NOTE #2:**
For those who are saying there is not enough room, here's a photoshopped screenshot proving that there is enough room:

[image]

Comment: The word "hummingbirds" is longer than 75px. Do you want that text cut off or hidden in some way or do you just want the box bigger?

Comment: Try flex https://jsfiddle.net/m6h37q2z/1/

Comment: @NenadVracar nice. I think that's what OP wants even tho it will look weird (see example: http://puu.sh/qDGrM/bb6f550956.png). OP, have you considered `word-break: break-all`?

Comment: I think OP wanted the padding to remain for every word except for "hummingbirds", which alone would act like the box had no padding.  Slightly different than @NenadVracar 's example.

Comment: @andi Nenad's code also results in the box being forced wider than 75px. That might be OK with the OP but they haven't clarified what that yet.

Comment: @BSMP, "hummingbirds" can fit within the gold box (it just needs to be centered).  Cutting off or hiding the text is unnecessary and would look horrible.

Comment: @NenadVracar, That solution removes the padding, which is a significant change to the design layout.

Comment: @Aziz, `word-break: break-all` makes the words unreadable (and it's overkill as there is enough room within the gold box).

Comment: **Photoshop is NOT the same as live HTML text** using an image editor to change this is quite different than how browsers render text and spacing.

Comment: @Scott, The Photoshopped image is to **prove** the the layout is possible.  It may not be possible to implement in CSS, but the layout itself is absolutely definitely possible.

Comment: @DemPilafian My answer below proves it can be done... but it also *proves it **shouldn't** be done.*

Comment: I see your Added Note #2, yet that photoshopped image DOESN'T take into account the padding being detailed in your CSS.  Remember, margin is space outside the gold, padding is space inside the gold. (Gold being the background color you've chosen for the area in discussion.)

Look at the element in your Chrome Dev Tools - press F12 on the page - and you'll see this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach using negative `letter-spacing` and using jQuery to detect long words (more than 8 chars) and wrapping them in a special span that is centered using negative `margin` and `display: block`:

```js
$('section p').each(function() {
  var p = $(this);
  var text = p.text();
  var words = text.split(' ');
  p.empty();
  $.each(words, function(i, w) {
    if (this.length > 8) {
      p.append("<span>" + this + "</span>");
    } else {
      p.append(w + ' ');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

section p {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gold;
  padding: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

section p span {
  display: block;
  margin:0 -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Some animals in the wild, like hummingbirds, have long names.</p>
  <p>Some animals in the wild, like oxen, have short names.</p>
  <p>Some animals in the wild, like varylawngstrung, have short names.</p>
  <p>Hellooooo my nameee isssssss whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat</p>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/bf52mwgr/

---

Also, If you want ridiculously long words to be broken, you could use this code, which will break words longer than 15 characters and restore the `inline` display:

```js
$('section p').each(function() {
  var p = $(this);
  var text = p.text();
  var words = text.split(' ');
  p.empty();
  $.each(words, function(i, w) {
    if (this.length > 8 && this.length < 16) {
      p.append("<span>" + w + " </span>");
    } else if (this.length > 15) {
      p.append("<span class='break'>" + w + " </span>");
    } else {
      p.append(w + ' ');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

section p {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gold;
  padding: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

section p span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 -200px;
}

section p span.break {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Some animals in the wild, like hummingbirds, have long names.</p>
  <p>Some animals in the wild, like hummingbirdsss, have long names.</p>
  <p>Some insects in the wild, like Parastratiosphecomyia, have huge names.</p>
</section>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8w3w2zh1/

Comment: This is a creative solution... it preserves the padding (and even works as well as possible for insanely long words).  I like it.

Comment: @DemPilafian I updated it to break very long words (optional)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is a straightforward to do this but there certainly are ways.

You can achieve this by using flexbox and wrapping some sections of your text with some `<span>` tags like so:

```
<section>
  <p>
    <span>Some animals in the wild, like</span>
    <span>hummingbirds,</span>
    <span>have long names.</span>
  </p>
</section>
```

Then you can add your styling like so:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

section {
  width: 115px;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

section p {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

As you can see I have changed a few things. Instead of adding `20px` of `padding` I have made the width of the parent container `40px` larger. because the `<section>` tag is using the `display: flex` property with `justified-content` the child `<p>` tag will be centered in the parent `<section>` (the `flex-direction` is default `row`.

Furthermore, each `<span>` within `<p>` is also center aligned (using `align-items` which aligns along the cross axis - the `flex-direction` is `column`.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0nq9pgt/

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Adding the `<span>` tags diminishes the semantics of the HTML, but this solution solves the problem and is totally workable.  It may be my best option.

Answer (score 1):

You have limited the width of `<p>` to `75px` only. But the space required for the word `hummingbirds,` is more than `75px`, that's why it can't fit in there. Try increasing the width of the `<p>`

```css
section p {
   width: 75px;
   text-align: center;
   background: gold;
   padding: 20px 0;
   }
```

```html
<section>
   <p>
      Some animals in the wild, like
      hummingbirds, have long names.
   </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Actually there is enough room (check out the screen shot in the question).  Expanding the width is not needed (and it would break the design).

Comment: @DemPilafian: jonju is correct.  What you're not considering is the padding that's being applied to the div.  That 20px padding to every side is killing your available width.  You're losing 40px total from the left and right padding.  There's simply not enough space for the word.  You'll need to change either the padding, the font size, or expand your width.

Comment: @freak, there definitely is enough room.  What you and jonju are talking about is an implementation detail (I'm fully aware of why the problem is occurring... however, the **layout is most definitely possible**, but it may be impossible to do in CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the box size can't be altered, the type size can't be altered.... to be honest I don't know how a word sticking out of it's container, even if it's centered, stays in line with any design but.....

One possible solution is to break long words...

```
section p {
   width: 75px;
   text-align: center;
   background: gold;
   padding: 20px;
   word-break: break-word;
   }
```

[image]

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/m6h37q2z/2/)

Grammatically it can be iffy, but visually it'll be consistent.

A less elegant solution may be to use a background image for the yellow (or a 1 color linear gradient) and then widen the paragraph, but position the 75px wide background centered in the (wider) paragraph.

Solution 3....

wrap long words in a `<span>` and then move the span.....

[image]

[**Fiddle update**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/m6h37q2z/4/)

or...

```
section p span { 
  display: inline-block; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: calc(100% + 20px); /* adds back padding area to inline-block */
  margin-left: -20px; /* counteracts paragraph padding offset */
  }
```

**[Fiddle Update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/m6h37q2z/7/)** Here you'd just need to wrap long words in a span... then the CSS should automatically overcome the padding.

I find this visually ***horrible*** and I'm a designer.

To the argument that "there's enough room"... well look above.. is there? It fits, sure, but by 1 pixel. And that's on *my* browser* on *my* system using *my* monitor. No clue how it may or may not work out on other displays. Logically it should be the same as what I see, but without testing who knows. That would not be acceptable to me.

The best, logical solution is to *RETHINK THE DESIGN* and either widen the box, use shorter words, or reduce the font-size.

Comment: There is already enough room within the gold box for the word "hummingbirds".

Comment: @DemPilafian without padding, yes.

Comment: @DemPilafian maybe.. See updated answer... remember it's not just the word.. there's a comma there too.

Comment: There is enough room for the comma, too.

Comment: Taking out the padding allows enough room for "hummingbirds" but breaks the layout.  It's possible that there is no CSS solution for this problem and I will have to hard-code line feeds, but that would be nasty.  I asked the question in the hope that someone had an awesome solution that I'd never seen.

Comment: With CSS not really... add javascript and you could calculate word lengths, automatically wrap long words in a span.. then the CSS would adjust. Padding is padding. It doesn't magically get ignored for a word in the middle of a paragraph.  There has to be some separate element there for CSS to act upon.

Comment: "visually horrible and I'm a designer."  Yes, if this all about a single box for a website on hummingbirds.  It's not.  I have a layout with dozens of boxes that are all the same size and the boxes look best with padding.  Every once in a while (about 1 in 20 boxes) there a long word that needs to stretch into the padding a small amount.  It would look fine, but the text must be centered (or it looks horrible).  Even if it's off-center by 2 pixels, it looks gross.  The "hummingbird" example is just for illustration (I'm not making a website to display cute little quotes about wild animals).

Answer (score 0):

You have but only so many options when it comes to this. You could change the font-size, or change the width. You could change overflow to either hidden or scroll. I am guessing though, that none of these really appeal to what you are trying to do. You could change the padding as well to compensate.

Comment: There may be many options, but changing the page design to workaround a CSS limitation is not an acceptable option.  There is already enough room within the gold box for the word "hummingbirds".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a simplified version of Aziz's solution (which I accepted as the answer).

If you want something really simple (but requires manually wrapping the long overflowing words in `span` tags), here's the solution:

**HTML**

```
<section>
   <p>
      Some animals in the wild, like
      <span>hummingbirds,</span> have long names.
   </p>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section p {
   width: 75px;
   text-align: center;
   background: gold;
   padding: 20px;
   }
section p span {
   display: block;
   margin: 0px -20px;
   }
```

Works great:
https://jsfiddle.net/m6h37q2z/8

Pure CSS (no Photoshop):
[image: Yep, it's possible]